# Input assisted doesn't show all suggestions

Tags: sapui5

I have input field i need suggest items from odata model.

```
           <Input
            id="productInput"
            type="Text"
            placeholder="Enter Product ..."
            showSuggestion="true"
            showValueHelp="true"
            valueHelpRequest="handleValueHelp"
            suggestionItems="{/ProductCollection}" >
            <suggestionItems>
                <core:Item text="{Name}" />
            </suggestionItems>
         </Input>
```

the problem is there are missing items : not all items are displayed (you can check this link 
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputAssisted/preview
it is the same behaviour when you put a for example it shows some items in the search it shows more with a )

Comment: are you using the same json model? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SAP/openui5/master/src/sap.ui.demokit/test/sap/ui/demokit/explored/products.json

Comment: no i am using an a odata model but regardless the model in the sample it doesn't show all items right ?

Comment: when you put any suggestion at first it gives you some items and when you put the same term in the search field it gives you more items

Comment: when you insert the letter "A" it will suggest all items which name begins with the letter "A"

Comment: no i tested that when you put "A" it will suggest 8 items or when you search for "a" in the search field as you can see it is a long list

Comment: I've just tested it [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputAssisted/preview) and at least on my browser it is not case sensitive, either "A" or "a" the input gives me the exact same suggestions

Comment: sorry @AndreF when i said search i mean the search filed in f 4 help list so if you put either "a" or "A" as asuggestion term you'll get a list with 8items now if you open the list and write on the search filed "a" or "A" and press enter you'll get a list

Comment: I see what you mean now, so you would like to display all of those items in the input suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is basically show all items that contains the value in the input. SAPUI5 has a convenient filter for this called `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains`.

The problem with the [`sap.m.Input`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input) is that it will only work one way, even if you manually set the Contains filter in the [`Suggest`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input/events/suggest) event, it will show suggestions that will start with the provided letter instead, just like `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.StartsWith` filter operator. That's why it is showing you less suggestions.

Using the same [`products.json`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SAP/openui5/master/src/sap.ui.demokit/test/sap/ui/demokit/explored/products.json) model in your question, we can do the following:

XML Input:

```
<Label text="Product" labelFor="productInput"/>
<Input
    id="productInput"
    type="Text"
    placeholder="Enter Product ..."
    showSuggestion="true"
    showValueHelp="false"
    suggest="handleSuggest"
    suggestionItems="{productsModel>/ProductCollection}" >
    <suggestionItems>
        <core:Item text="{productsModel>Name}" />
    </suggestionItems>
</Input>
```

Controller:

```
handleSuggest: function (oEvent) {
    var aFilters = [];
    var sTerm = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue");
    if (sTerm) {
        aFilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Name", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sTerm));
    }
    oEvent.getSource().getBinding("suggestionItems").filter(aFilters);
    //do not filter the provided suggestions before showing them to the user - important
    oEvent.getSource().setFilterSuggests(false);
}
```

It is very important to set the [`setFilterSuggests()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input/methods/setFilterSuggests) method to **false** in order not to filter the provided suggestions before showing them to the user, this would go against we just did previously.

Using this approach, the suggested item will show only those values filtered by the specified filter condition which is `sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains`.

[Other SAPUI5 Filter Operators](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.FilterOperator)

Comment: thank you this is a helpful answer but  is there another way without the suggest function because i am doing other filters on the odata directly depending on other fields  so this filter in the handler  will override my filters in the suggestion.

Comment: you can apply the same method to the suggestionItems on the input